# Showing a function is continuous in the proof of existence of Lebesgue number

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I was trying to understand the proof of the existence of the Lebesgue number of an open covering of a compact metric space. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open covering of the compact metric space $(X,d)$. Then there exists a finite subcollection $\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ that covers $X$. Let $C_i=X-A_i$. Define a map, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, as 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nd(x,C_i)$$ where $d(y,S)=\inf\{d(y,a)~:~a\in S)\}$ for any $S\subset X$ and any $y\in X$. The rest is not hard to show if I can claim that **this function is continuous**, which would then imply that it has a minimum in the compact space $X$.

How do I show that this function is continuous? Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\emptyset \neq A \subset X$, the distance function $f(x) = d(x,A): X \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is always continuous on a metric space, as $|f(x) - f(x')| \le d(x,x')$ for all $x, x'\in X$ by triangle inequalities.

The rest is finite  sums and scalar multiplications of those functions.

Comment: Oh thanks much. It was so obvious, i dont know why i never noticed.